# elementary OS non-uefi installation?

Tags: system-installation, boot, dual-boot

i've been pulling my hair out because of this, so i had a dual boot(non UEFI, normal BIOS) of windows 8.1 and ubuntu 14.04 and i decided to replace ubuntu with elementary OS 64 bit then installation fails saying `package grub-pc failed to install at /target/` so i choose don't install boot loader, after that i boot into the live system again and try `grub-install /dev/sda` but i get the error `/usr/lib/grub/i386-pc/modinit.sh` doesn't exist, i would greatly appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: Re-installing while connected to the internet should fix the problem, assuming you weren't before.

Comment: @Lewis Gooddard, tried that but no luck

Comment: same problem here... installing while connected to the internet doesn't solve the problem

Comment: what is your exact problem?....not able to boot to any OS?

Comment: @zola let me know my answer is useful to you =)

Comment: grub-install gives the error i wrote in my question.

Comment: turn off your computer, and turn it on again (not reboot)

Answer (score 1):

Open terminal and run:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda6 /mnt
sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sda
sudo update-grub
```

**Note**: In first command /dev/sda6 is elementary OS  `/root` partition.Replace `6` with your partition number.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I solved this using a live cd to chroot into the target system, then installing grub-pc.

Instructions on how to chroot can be found here: http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd

Before you run the grub-install command, run sudo apt-get install grub-pc